# Fastest way to calculate cosine similartity between two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have one array A containing 64000 embeddings and an other array B containing 12000 embeddings (each of the embedding is 1024 floats long).

Now I want to calculate the cosine similarity for all the pairs between array A and array B (cartesian product).

To perform that (using pandas), I merge array A with array B using `.merge(how="cross")`.
It gives me 768 000 000 pairs.

Now I am looking for the fastest way of calculating the cosine sim. for now I used something like this using Numpy:

```
def compute_cosine_sim(a, b):
    return dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))

np.vectorize(compute_cosine_sim)(df.embedding_A.to_numpy(), df.embedding_B.to_numpy())
```

To keep the RAM at reasonable level, I use pandas Dataframe chunking.

The problem is my method is not. fast enough, and I was wondering if there wasn't something to change here, especially regarding the effectiveness of the numpy function I use.

To give some details, I reach 130000 iter/sec with this function, is it normal ?
Also, could this kind of operation be run on GPU easily ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could matrix multiply embedding A with the transpose of embedding B to get the dot products of all pairs, and then divide the output along the columns by the norm of the vectors in A, and the rows by the norm of the vectors in B:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(10, 4)
b = np.random.randn(8, 4)

out = a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) / np.linalg.norm(b.T, axis=0, keepdims=True)
# out has shape (10, 8)
```